# verify input isn't working properly in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I basically created this game that generates balls of random number on the screen based on the number of balls user types in to display, Then on the right side, he has to input the ball numbers in order and click verify, if he gets it right, it says "correct" otherwise it says "Sorry the correct number is " then is shows the actual order of the numbers. The problem is, whenever i click on verify, the result is always correct, even if i didn't input any number or even if the numbers r wrong. What is the mistake i am making? here r my codes: I will put a command next to the verify part of the program so it can be easier for u to locate the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload=draw;
var xArr=[];
var choose;
 function draw(){
    var canvas= document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;
    var r;
    var i;

    var balls=[{"id":1,"x":85,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":2,"x":180,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":3,"x":270,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":4,"x":360,"y":90,"r":40},
    {"id":5,"x":450,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":6,"x":535,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":7,"x":623,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":8,"x":710,"y":90,"r":40},
    {"id":9,"x":85,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":10,"x":180,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":11,"x":270,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":12,"x":360,"y":190,"r":40},
    {"id":13,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":14,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":15,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":16,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40},
    {"id":17,"x":85,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":18,"x":180,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":19,"x":270,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":20,"x":360,"y":290,"r":40},
    {"id":21,"x":450,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":22,"x":535,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":23,"x":623,"y":290,"r":40},{"id":24,"x":710,"y":290,"r":40},
    {"id":25,"x":85,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":26,"x":180,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":27,"x":270,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":28,"x":360,"y":390,"r":40},
    {"id":29,"x":450,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":30,"x":535,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":31,"x":623,"y":390,"r":40},{"id":32,"x":710,"y":390,"r":40},
    {"id":33,"x":85,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":34,"x":180,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":35,"x":270,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":36,"x":360,"y":490,"r":40},
    {"id":37,"x":450,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":38,"x":535,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":39,"x":623,"y":490,"r":40},{"id":40,"x":710,"y":490,"r":40},
    {"id":41,"x":85,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":42,"x":180,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":43,"x":270,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":44,"x":360,"y":590,"r":40},
    {"id":45,"x":450,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":46,"x":535,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":47,"x":623,"y":590,"r":40},{"id":48,"x":710,"y":590,"r":40},
    {"id":49,"x":85,"y":690,"r":40},{"id":50,"x":85,"y":690,"r":40}];
    var texts=[];
    for(i=1;i<=balls.length;i++){
      texts[i]=i;
    }
    var x=[];

    var t=[];
    var xstep=0;
    choose=parseFloat(prompt("enter the number of balls u want to see"));

    for (i=0; i<choose; i++) {       
       var b = getRandomBall();
            x.push(b);          
            ctx.fillStyle = "#800000";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.beginPath();
            xstep=xstep+120;
            var ystep=90;
            ctx.arc(xstep, ystep, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText(b.id, xstep, ystep);

            console.log(i);
            $(".selected").append('<label>Enter a number: </label><input type="text" name="userNumber'+i+'" id="userNumber'+i+'"><br /><br />');

    }


    function getRandomBall(){ 
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * balls.length);
    return balls.splice(r,1)[0];  
    }
     xArr = x;

    }
  draw()

</script>
<body>
<div id="leftside" width="900" height="1000" style="border: 2px solid #000000">
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border: 2px solid #000000">
</canvas>
<div id="rightside" width="300" height="800" style="border 2px solid #000000; float: right; margin-right:100px;">

<form action="#" method="get" >

<div class="selected"></div>
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify">
<hr>

</form>


the result is:
<div id="result" style="font-size: 14px"></div> 


</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){                           //here is the issue
    for (i=0; i<choose; i++) {
     $("#verifyBtn").click(function(){

                    if(($('#userNumber'+i).val()==xArr[i])){
                            $("#result").css({color:'green'});
                            $("#result").text("correct");

                        }
                        else{
                            $("#result").css({color:'red'});
                            $("#result").text("sorry: try again"+ " correct number was "+xArr);
                        }

                })

    }



        })
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Start by not putting the event handler inside a loop that iterates for every ball

Comment: where do i put it then? I tried it but it didn't work. There is a matter with the verification part i think